# Django ORM: have model field always return a constant

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I am extending Django model into a few child classes:

```
Model
    –> SampleModel
         –> SampleModelA
         –> SampleModelB 
         –> SampleModelC
         –> SampleModelD
```

All child models (A,B,C,D) have field `SampleType` as Integer.
Models A and B may have different SampleTypes (1–5), whereas for models C and D, `SampleType` is always the same: 1 and 2, respectively.

I must preserve `SampleType` field in all child models for polymorphism purposes, but need models C and D always return 1 and 2, respectively for that field in any record, no matter what query.

What is the simplest way to do that? (preferably without taking up disk space for the field)